# Query returns value that don't exist in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Is there a way to create a subset dataframe from a dataframe and be sure that its values will be used afterward?

I have a huge PySpark Dataframe like this (simplified example):

| id | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1658919602 | 5 |
| 1 | 1658919604 | 9 |
| 2 | 1658919632 | 2 |

Now I want to take a sample from it to test something, before running on the entire Dataframe. I get a sample by:

```
# Big dataframe
df = ...

# Create sample
df_sample = df.limit(10)
```

`df_sample.show()` shows some values.

Then I run this command, and sometimes it returns values that are present in `df_sample` and sometimes it returns values that are not present in `df_sample` but in `df`.

`df_temp = df_sample.sort(F.desc('timestamp')).groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('newcol'))`

As if it's not using `df_sample` but picking in a non deterministic way 10 rows from `df`.

Interestingly, if I run `df_sample.show()` afterwards, it shows the same values as when it was first called.

Why is this happening?

Here's full code:

```
# Big dataframe
df = ...

# Create sample
df_sample = df.limit(10)

# shows some values
df_sample.show()

# run query
df_temp = df_sample.sort(F.desc('timestamp')).groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('newcol')

# df_temp sometimes shows values that are present in df_sample, but sometimes shows values that aren't present in df_sample but in df
df_temp.show()

# Shows the exact same values as when it was first called
df_sample.show()
```

Edit1: I understand that Spark is lazy, but is there any way to force it to not be lazy in this scenario?

Comment: spark being lazy will rerun `limit(10)` and get a random sample every time you run your process. a potential way to bypass it would be to persist the sample df before the `show()`. `df_sample = df.limit(10)` `df_sample.persist()` `df_sample.show()` `df_temp = df_sample.sort...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was using `df_sample = df.limit(10).cache()` or `df_sample = df.limit(10).persist()`. Samkart's comment pointed me in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

We can use sample function provided by spark to achieve this.Every time you run a sample() function it returns a different set of sampling records, To regenerate the same sample every time as you need to compare the results from your previous run. To get consistent same random sampling uses the same slice value for every run.

```
df=spark.range(100)
# Execute first time
print(df.sample(0.1,123).collect())

# Execute Second time with same seed-123
print(df.sample(0.1,123).collect())

# Execute with different seed-456
print(df.sample(0.1,456).collect())
```

[Refer spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample.html)

[Stratum sampling in spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sampleBy.html)

Comment: This is great if I want to randomly sample from Dataframe. What if I want to pick first N rows? E.g. dataframe is sorted.

Comment: @Alcibiades we can use sampleBy() method and get N rows eg. sampled = df.sampleBy("id", fractions={0: 0.1}, seed=0)
sampled.groupBy("id").orderBy("timestamp").show()